# How can I crawl Twitter data using OAuth

Tags: twitter, oauth, web-crawler

How can I use read only access to twitter API using OAuth authentication to crawl the twitter data like user timeline, followers, following-list etc. I used to use BasicAuth but now its not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what platform you're working with, but the "how to connect with Oauth" problem has been solved multiple times on just about every platform.  Rather than writing this code yourself (and giving yourself a thousand headaches), you may be better served finding one of the many Twitter libraries out there that already support OAuth.